# PySide2 segfault in Qt main thread (0xC0000005)

Tags: segmentation-fault, pyside2, python-3.10, pyside6

*Windows 10. Currently using Python 3.10, PySide2/Qt 5.15.2.*

Our Python/PySide2 application (tested with PySide2 and PySide6 - official builds installed via pip) rarely and seemingly randomly segfaults in the Qt UI main thread.
Running the Python interpeter in a debugger yielded the following information:

1. The Qt thread will segfault in a different Qt library function every time
2. All of these functions have the exact same assembly level structure:

> ```
> mov qword ptr [rcx], 0
> mov rax, rcx
> ```

3. The crashing instruction is always: mov qword ptr [rcx],0
4. ... because RCX is 0

It's a rather massive data processing/visualization app with two entirely independent components (no data/code sharing at all). We're using openpyxl to parse excel sheets and pandas to manipulate data.

The problem seems to occur primarily if, without exiting the programm, the visualization component has been used prior to the data processing.

Segfaults will happen while running work (like applying changes to a pandas data frame) in a background thread eventhough the segfaulting thread is the Qt UI main thread.

Using the Python faulthandler module, I've managed to extract approximate tracebacks from these background threads, but the traceback will look different almost every time:

```
Thread 0x00004504 (most recent call first):
  File "pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 974 in is_dtype
  File "pandas\core\dtypes\common.py", line 456 in is_period_dtype
  File "pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 355 in _get_getitem_freq
  File "pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py", line 348 in __getitem__
  File "pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 629 in __iter__
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 995 in series_generator
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 865 in apply_series_generator
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 851 in apply_standard
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 727 in apply
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 8839 in apply
  File "essence\data_manager\model\cubes.py", line 443 in _create_cohort
  File "essence\data_manager\model\cubes.py", line 91 in __init__
  File "essence\data_manager\model\cube_manager.py", line 1454 in create_cubes
  File "essence\data_manager\controller\worker.py", line 104 in _work
  File "essence\data_manager\controller\worker.py", line 31 in work
  File "threading.py", line 910 in run
  File "threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap



Thread 0x00003f4c (most recent call first):
  File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 5538 in __finalize__
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 3915 in _box_col_values
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 3442 in _ixs
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 3932 in _get_item_cache
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 3474 in __getitem__
  File "pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 873 in get_grouper
  File "pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 882 in __init__
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 7712 in groupby
  File "pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 407 in _generate_marginal_results
  File "pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 292 in _add_margins
  File "pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 228 in __internal_pivot_table
  File "pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 95 in pivot_table
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 8038 in pivot_table
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\analyses\abstract_analysis.py", line 278 in pivot
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\analyses\double_pivot.py", line 114 in create_singe_pivots
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\analyses\double_pivot.py", line 94 in single_pivots
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\analyses\double_pivot.py", line 182 in __init__
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\model_abstract.py", line 348 in double_pivot
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\model_abstract.py", line 335 in execute_analysis
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\model_abstract.py", line 110 in create_analysis
  File "essence\analysis_module\model\model_abstract.py", line 100 in update_analysis
  File "essence\analysis_module\controller.py", line 82 in update_analysis
  File "essence\ui\utils.py", line 37 in run



Thread 0x00004254 (most recent call first):
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1656 in _start
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1722 in feed
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1303 in feed
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1265 in iterator
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 144 in parse
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_read_only.py", line 79 in _cells_by_row
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 468 in values
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 308 in <listcomp>
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 308 in load_xlsx
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 57 in load_preview
  File "essence\data_manager\model\cube_manager.py", line 84 in load_preview
  File "essence\ui\utils.py", line 37 in run



Thread 0x000048fc (most recent call first):
  File "threading.py", line 312 in wait
  File "concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 441 in result
  File "concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 609 in result_iterator
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 559 in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 357 in load_xlsx
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 107 in load_full
  File "essence\data_manager\model\cube_manager.py", line 98 in load_full
  File "essence\data_manager\controller\worker.py", line 70 in _work
  File "essence\data_manager\controller\worker.py", line 31 in work
  File "threading.py", line 910 in run
  File "threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 930 in _bootstrap



Thread 0x00000b50 (most recent call first):
  File "threading.py", line 833 in __init__
  File "concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 194 in _adjust_thread_count
  File "concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 176 in submit
  File "pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 603 in dataframe_to_arrays
  File "pandas\io\parquet.py", line 174 in write
  File "pandas\io\parquet.py", line 420 in to_parquet
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 2835 in to_parquet
  File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 207 in wrapper
  File "essence\project_file.py", line 446 in _serialize_df
  File "essence\project_file.py", line 468 in _write
  File "essence\project_file.py", line 463 in save_element
  File "essence\data_manager\controller_datamanager.py", line 2003 in _work
  File "essence\ui\utils.py", line 37 in run



Thread 0x0000169c (most recent call first):
  File "openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 143 in __set__
  File "openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 49 in __init__
  File "openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103 in from_tree
  File "openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87 in from_tree
  File "openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87 in from_tree
  File "openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87 in from_tree
  File "openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103 in from_tree
  File "openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198 in apply_stylesheet
  File "openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 281 in read
  File "openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317 in load_workbook
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 295 in load_xlsx
  File "essence\data_manager\model\file_loader.py", line 57 in load_preview
  File "essence\data_manager\model\cube_manager.py", line 84 in load_preview
  File "essence\ui\utils.py", line 37 in run
```

Every traceback is from a different runtime/process of the app.

Based on how different they are, I've no idea how (if at all) the segfaulting Qt thread is related to the backend thread.

Some threads will be started as a QRunnable in a ThreadPool, others are QThreads. Doesn't seem to be directly related to how a thread is started.

I've since gone through different versions of thread management code without fixing the problem.

The problem can not be reproduced reliably at all.

Would appreciate litterally any insight, can provide minidumps/corefiles.

---

Comment: And what do you do in those functions? Please provide a [mre] or at least a more detailed description of what the program does and what happens. Also, we need more insight about the configuration, OS, Python/Qt versions, etc.

Comment: Added some more information. It's difficult to create a minimal reproducible example because I cannot reproduce the issue reliably.

Comment: What OS? Do you use threading? Did you try to run the program in a terminal or prompt? Did you try to make test programs that mimic the actual one but leaving out one of those two components? I know it might be difficult, but without a MRE or any code-related details it's almost impossible to understand *where* the problem is.

Comment: There's no shortcut to debugging issues like this. You need to use a very crude divide and conquer approach to find the relevant section of the code. Make a clone of your project and then start removing big chunks of it whilst emplying whatever hackery is needed to keep reproducing the problem. You might think this is impossible at first because your project has become so large, but it really isn't. No project is ever so complex that it's impossible to produce a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not using any QT function that changes anything in the GUI inside any thread except the main thread, otherwise you will run into a segmentation fault. emitting signals from threads is fine, and the main thread should catch those signals and update the GUI.

other than that, sometimes shiboken, pyside2 and python have version compatibility issues, so downgrading them all to something stable helps.

Comment: PySide2 (and shiboken as a dependency) are being installed via pip from the official mirrors. The issue also persists across versions - PySide2/PySide6 seem to be equally affected.

Comment: I've made sure that no UI calls are made in any thread except the main thread. As mentioned before, the crashing thread is the UI thread.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Were you able to come out this ?